# Toast notification Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm writing an application for iOS in Xamarin (C#).

What is the equivalent of Android's 'toast notifications' in iOS?

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html):

> A toast provides simple feedback about an operation in a small popup. It only fills the amount of space required for the message and the current activity remains visible and interactive. For example, navigating away from an email before you send it triggers a "Draft saved" toast to let you know that you can continue editing later. Toasts automatically disappear after a timeout.

For example in Android (C#) I can show them like this:

```
Toast.MakeText(this, "Added " + counttext.Text +" pcs to cart" , ToastLength.Long).Show();
```

How do I write the same for iOS?

Thank's for answer.

Answer (score 11):

In Xamarin iOS you have to use custom designed UIView with animation to achieve the same effect

```
public void ShowToast(String message, UIView view)
    {
        UIView residualView = view.ViewWithTag(1989);
        if (residualView != null)
            residualView.RemoveFromSuperview();

        var viewBack = new UIView(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(83, 0, 300, 100));
        viewBack.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        viewBack.Tag = 1989;
        UILabel lblMsg = new UILabel(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 20, 300, 60));
        lblMsg.Lines = 2;
        lblMsg.Text = message;
        lblMsg.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        lblMsg.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        viewBack.Center = view.Center;
        viewBack.AddSubview(lblMsg);
        view.AddSubview(viewBack);
        roundtheCorner(viewBack);
        UIView.BeginAnimations("Toast");
        UIView.SetAnimationDuration(3.0f);
        viewBack.Alpha = 0.0f;
        UIView.CommitAnimations();
    }
```

Comment: How to pass UIView if interface is defined in Portable and its implementation is in ios project, and I am trying to show toast notification from portable?

Comment: This one is not meant to be shown from Portable.You can show this from Xamarin.iOS side

Comment: Suppose i have made interface in portable and its implementation in Ios project then how can I pass UIview to this?

Comment: @Sonali - I never tried this before ... Portable is supposed to be platform independent so having iOS Specific code over there will contradict the very purpose.You can use this on xamarin.iOS side and I don't think that would be hard

Comment: The simplest solution I found and for roundTheCorner use viewBack.Layer.CornerRadius=10;
   viewBack.Layer.MasksToBounds=true;

Answer (score 4):

Use the Xamarin built-in component BigTed

https://components.xamarin.com/view/btprogresshud

`BTProgressHUD.ShowToast("Hello from Toast");`

Answer (score 2):

You can try 
    https://github.com/andrius-k/Toast

It is available as nuget package Toast.ios
usage:

```
// import
using GlobalToast;
Toast.MakeToast("message").SetDuration(0.5).Show();
```

Comment: tried with this but getting error to use Toast. Getting null reference

Answer (score 0):

As of **iOS 9**, the [**UIAlertController**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIAlertController/) class is recommended for displaying feedback to the user.

Example usage:

```
var alertController = UIAlertController.Create("Your Count", "Added 1 PC", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

alertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, (action) => Console.WriteLine("OK Clicked.")));

PresentViewController(alertController, true, null);
```

One thing to bare in mind is that you must be in a [**UIViewController**](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIViewController/) in order to present the alert. This is due to the fact that a **UIAlertController** is a subclass of a **UIViewController**.

Comment: "What is the equivalent of Android's 'toast notifications' in iOS?" I'm sorry, but this is not the equivalent, for dismiss it you have to do an action.